# how to keep track of reminder which is saved in iphone or ipad?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, eventkit, reminders

I am working on this application that will save reminder. but i do not know how to keep track of saved reminder.
In the Case of event we have eventIdentifier but for Reminder i am getting nothing like that.

I am using realm to save data and using REST API.while fetching data from server i am creating objects and at that time i am also creating realm objects and creating reminder.  but i don't know how to check that reminder is added for that object or not.

Comment: do you want to save data? if yes check this link: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-data-persistence-and-sandboxing-on-ios--cms-25505

Comment: you can use userDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples.  One for RealmObject, one for ReminderObject:

```
import Foundation

class RealmObject: NSObject {}
class ReminderObject: NSObject {}

let realmObject = RealmObject()
let reminderObject = ReminderObject()

// To save objects...
UserDefaults.standard.set(realmObject, forKey: "realmObject")
UserDefaults.standard.set(reminderObject, forKey: "reminderObject")

// To retrieve objects...
let retrievedRealm   = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "realmObject") as? RealmObject
let retrievedReminder = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "reminderObject") as? ReminderObject
```

Comment: lets take two realm object and two reminder objects then how can we identify for which realm object which reminder object is their